# Single product discount cart price rule not working in magento 2.2.4?

Tags: product, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, magento2.2.4

I have created cart rule for single product, in my cart rule I have added one condition for single brands.
check below screen-shot fore more information.

[image]

[image]

[image]

When We set rule only single product then rule apply all cart products.
Can anyone advise what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add condition in `Action` tab cart item matching only http://prntscr.com/mfak4u

Other wise it will apply to all cart item even single item match